# How do I get a link to ignore hover on mouseover?

Tags: html, css

Currently I have my site set up so that links have an underline on mouseover. How do I get it so that some links ignore this?

My code:

```
a:hover { 
border-bottom: solid #000 2px !important;}
```

The HTML that I don't want to have this applied to it:

```html
<div class="banner">
<h1><a href="home.html" class="titleLink">Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</a></h1>
```

I assume maybe I apply text-decoration: none to my h1, but the issue is selecting my h1 in css. None of my different attempts were working so I think I was writing the selector wrong. How would I write a selector in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, remove `!important`. It is unnecessary and makes things more difficult than they need to be.

Then, assuming `.titleLink` is your "don't put hover effect on this" class, just do...

```
a.titleLink:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Done.

Comment: This is the best answer. There is no need to add another class, assuming the `.titleLink` is only used when you don't want the hover effect anyway.

Comment: If box sizing is *not* being used the a transparent border might be an alternative.

Comment: I did this and it worked, but now the mouseover effect I had doesn't show up in the browser. That was the original reason that I had added the !important.

Answer (score 1):

```
.banner h1 a:hover { 
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.banner h1 a:hover { border-bottom: none !important; text-decoration: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

Add a new class

**CSS**

```
a.noborder:hover { 
border-bottom: none !important;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">
<h1><a href="home.html" class="titleLink noborder">Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</a></h1>
```

Comment: Yours was the answer that worked! Thanks! Is there a reason why the bottom border wasn't showing up without the !important? I had to add it because originally the effect wasn't showing up.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the property by class. So you can write:

`.titleLink:hover {text-decoration: none;}`

Hope it helps.

You can make it more reusable by writing a class

`.noDeco:hover {text-decoration: none;}`

and then use it as class for links where you don't want the underline.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a:hover specific for titleLink class:

```
a.titleLink:hover {
   border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

Or if you are using that class in other parts of page, you need to define new class or helper class for that particular link.

Answer (score 0):

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  border-bottom: solid #000;
}
.borderBottom0 {
  border-bottom: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <h1><a href="home.html" class="titleLink">Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</a></h1>
  <h1><a href="home.html" class="titleLink borderBottom0">Brian Funderburke Photography &amp; Design</a></h1>
```